# Repeater Error when used twice

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Repeater, which contains several ImageButton elements. The first time I add a list of images to the Datasource of that Repeater, it works perfectly fine:

```
Repeater.DataSource = images;
Repeater.DataBind();
```

I have a TextChanged - event somewhere and inside that Event, I want to overwrite the DataSource with a new list of images.

When I do that, I receive a CallBack error. Commenting out the first DataBind makes the second one work perfectly. How can I resolve that problem?

**Edit:** The error message I receive is in german (here: http://i.imgur.com/M9wxexm.jpg), but roughly translated, it means: Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using <.pages enableEventValidation=“true”/.> ...

Comment: can you post the actual error too?

Comment: @techspider Sorry, I edited it to include the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting a `callback` error, you should try disabling event validation for your aspx page. This needs to be done in page directive which will be at top of your aspx page.

```
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false"%>
```

Also keep the following facts in mind.

1. For the first databind, I am assuming it's in the `Page_Load` event. If that is the case then make sure that it's only executed when page is not posting back since on page post back you have text changed logic to populate the repeater.

   ```
   protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e) 
   {
     if(!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
       Repeater.DataSource = images;
       Repeater.DataBind();
      }
   }
   ```
2. Then in your text changed event databind the same repeater and make sure you call the `DataBind` method after setting it's data source.  So, include both the lines below in your text changed event handler. Of course, the `images` variable needs to be replaced by the appropriate variable in text-changed event.

   ```
       Repeater.DataSource = images;
       Repeater.DataBind();
   ```

Comment: The first Databind is indeed in the Page_Load event, but I made sure it is inside the !IsPostBack. Both Databinds are executed after the Datasource was changed.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. The error message is in german (http://i.imgur.com/M9wxexm.jpg), but roughly translated, it says: Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using '<pages enableEventValidation=“true”/>' ...

Comment: Oh ok. Then do one thing. Go to your aspx page and go to the page directive at top of page that says `<%@ Page ...` and set `EnableEventValidation="false"`.

Comment: You are changing some server-side property of  a control from JavaScript and this causes event validation to throw an error.

Comment: The only JavaScript I use is to clear the text when I click on the TextBox. Could that be the cause?

Comment: Ye could be. But the best is to set EnableEventValidation="false"

Comment: Sorry, I only saw the second comment. That solved it! Can you make an answer so I can upvote and approve?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)